# call pthread_cond_broadcast with mutex held or not?

Tags: c, locking, pthreads

With a pthread_cond_t we have to associate a mutex, When signalling the condition I've seen code such as

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

//code that makes condition true

pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

and

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

//code that makes condition true

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
```

Which one is the proper way ? (Does it matter ?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Depends what the sinks are doing (and any other sources).

In your second code sample, it's possible that in between unlock and broadcast, a bunch of other threads will come along and do some combination of things which makes the condition false again. You'll then be broadcasting pointlessly. And you won't necessarily have the same set of waiters as were there when you changed the condition, which may or may not affect your design.

A decent sink shouldn't care if it gets woken up and the condition is false, especially if you're using broadcast. As long as every change of condition to "true" is eventually followed by a broadcast, I'm pretty sure that with appropriately-written sinks, you can broadcast a condition variable willy-nilly with or without the lock.

So I don't think it really matters, but personally I'd broadcast with the lock held, if only to avoid having to worry about it. "Atomic change-and-signal" might simplify the state diagram on your whiteboard compared with "change ... some time later, signal".

Both are proper (unlike waiting without the mutex, which isn't allowed), but I don't think it would be too difficult to come up with uses which can go wrong in the second case, that wouldn't go wrong in the first. They'd probably have to involve some waiters doing slightly unusual things, though.

The spec rather cryptically says "if predictable scheduling behavior is required, then that mutex shall be locked by the thread calling pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal()."

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html

Comment: Having the same question I have found your answer. I have followed your link and I think that he bit that you quote is related to the earlier bit: "If more than one thread is blocked on a condition variable, the scheduling policy shall determine the order in which threads are unblocked."

Comment: @wilx: yes, my concern is what's allowed by "unpredictable scheduling behavior". For example, suppose that you have a scheduler that's documented, or has an option, that mutexes and condition variables choose the thread to wake on a FIFO basis. Does the "cryptic" sentence imply that behavior is not expected to be FIFO if a caller of `pthread_cond_signal` isn't holding the mutex? I would think so, but I don't know the formal definition of "predictable", so that's why I find it cryptic. Except in a RT system I always treat scheduling as a bit unpredictable, but I don't want it to get bizarre.

Comment: There is no known case where it matters whether your broadcast before or after the unlock. With great difficulty, one can construct code that breaks if you move a signal to after an unlock.

Comment: @David: no known pthread_cond_broadcast case on any Posix implementation ever, is that? Does the difficulty of constructing a pthread_cond_signal case depend on the OS, or are all relevant condvar implementation details on all Posix systems effectively identical? What I was unsure of in answering the question (and what I'm still unsure of) is how much leeway Posix implementers think that they're given by a program doing something that means "predictable scheduler behavior" is not required.

Comment: If predictable scheduler behavior is required, you must be using thread priorities. That's the only way you can ever get predictable scheduler behavior. As for creating a pthread_cond_signal case, it's not an implementation issue, it's a pure semantic issue. You need the meaning of the condition to change based on the predicate such that the 'wrong' thread to wake up can only go to sleep after the unlock. It's very tricky to create such a case. (With broadcast, it matters not if the wrong thread wakes up so long as the right one wakes too.)